Can every element in a RKHS be represented as a series in kernel functionals?
I am again reading this paper and in my effort to carefully get all the details right, and I am stumped on the following: Let $(\mathcal{H},\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_{\mathcal{H}})$ be your run-of-the-mill reproducing kernel hilbert space (RKHS) under some (continuous, conjugate symmetric) positive definite kernel
$$K: U \times U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
As one can show with a bit of effort, the standard completion (including limit points and defining the inner product by the limit of the inner product sequences) is well-defined and unique under some mild conditions. We especially have that
$$\mathcal{H} = \overline{\text{span}\{K_x: x \in U\}}$$
where $K_x := K(\cdot,x)$.
On page 10 of the linked paper, they claim that

Every element $g \in \mathcal{H}$ can be expressed as a linear combination
$$g(x) = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{M} \alpha_j K(x'_j,x)$$
for some $M \in \mathbb{N}$, $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x'_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, barring the confusing claim that $g$ is a finite sum (which seems unlikely to be true since we are talking about the closure of the span of such functions), the thing I am most unsure about is

If we allow $M \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ for a moment, is it true that every element $g \in \mathcal{H}$ is representable as an infinite sum of it's generating span? If not, what were the authors trying to imply here?

I have tried to apply this questions counterexample to this example, but I couldn't quite figure it out and the nice properties of RKHS have me in doubt if the fact might not even be false after all! Thank you for reading.

A minor note: $K_x : X \to \mathbb R$ usually denotes the function $x' \mapsto k(x',x)$ for fixed $x$ and not the evaluation functional $\delta_x : H \to \mathbb R$ (where $X$ is the set on which the kernel $k$ associated to $H$ is defined).

@Flo Yes, you are correct.

@Flo Why did you delete your answer? I might have just interpreted the statement wrongly, no need to be this drastic.

I want to give it some more thought. In particular, contrasting this and this got me confused.
